# Can we use the overall F test from a regression to explain the effect of a categorical model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I'm fitting a linear regression model where the continuous variable is "Score" and there are two independent variables:

1. Continuous variable "Age"
2. Categorical variable with 3 levels "Group"

Model:  $Score=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\cdot age+\beta _{2}\cdot group_{1}+\beta _{3}\cdot group_{2}+\beta _{4}\cdot group_{3}$

The result is as follows. I want to evaluate the overall effect of the categorical variable "Group" on score.

Just wondering if I use the P-value related to the F test of overall significant (P-value = 0.9926 at the bottom) to conclude that there "Group" variable has no significant effect on the "Score" after adjusting for "Age"?

````
Call:
lm(formula = score ~ age + group, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-14.413  -4.131  -1.005   4.942  17.629 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 75.287200   9.967389   7.553  3.8e-10 ***
age         -0.074916   0.615699  -0.122    0.904    
group2      -0.006587   1.194113  -0.006    0.996   
group3      -0.005221   2.292110  -0.002    0.856   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.509 on 57 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0002607, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03482 
F-statistic: 0.007431 on 2 and 57 DF,  p-value: 0.9926
```
````

Answer (score 1):

A quick note: The $\beta$ for your base group should collapse into the intercept (I cannot recall how R denotes the base group, but it is systematic, yet arbitrary choice). So you only want to have two $\beta$s for groups in your equation above.

If wonder if your data is not setup correctly? For example if you do:

```
lm(formula = Petal.Width~Species,data = iris,x = T)
```

Result:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris, x = T)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-0.626 -0.126 -0.026  0.154  0.474 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        0.24600    0.02894    8.50 1.96e-14 ***
Speciesversicolor  1.08000    0.04093   26.39  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica   1.78000    0.04093   43.49  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2047 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9289,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9279 
F-statistic:   960 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

you will see a $\beta$ estimate for each two of the three levels of Species ("Setosa" is collapsed into the intercept). So perhaps your "group" column is not a factor? If your F test is insignificant, you can cite the F test. But if the F test is significant, you'll want to look at your covariates and find which one is setting off the alarm.

Comment: Thanks Trillium, yes I converted my "group" column into factor and re-edited my post. Just wondering: in my model, except for the categorical variable "group", there is also an "age" variable. If F-test is not significant (in which the overall P-value > 0.05), can I say that there is no significant effect across the 3 groups, with the existence of the "age" variable?

Comment: Correct, if all of the assumptions have been met. I've seen some wacky cases where the betas and F value disagreed because of violations to the homoscedasticity assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an F test for the overall contribution of the `group` variable by using the `anova` function with two nested models. Below is a quick example of how to do it. As you can see, since the `group` variable was not in the original simulated model, the anova table indicates that the null hypothesis, the simpler model, is preferred.

```r
set.seed(3)

x <- runif(100)

y <- 2 + 3*x + rnorm(100, sd=4)

group <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), replace=T, size=100)

model1 <- lm(y ~ 1 + x)

summary(model1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ 1 + x)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -9.5565 -2.6655  0.6029  2.6292  7.8328 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)   1.8731     0.7285   2.571   0.0116 *
#> x             3.0821     1.2970   2.376   0.0194 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.695 on 98 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.05448,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.04483 
#> F-statistic: 5.647 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.01943

model2 <- lm(y ~ 1 + x + group)

summary(model2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ 1 + x + group)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -9.1657 -2.6963  0.4279  2.5717  8.2469 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)   2.0257     0.9100   2.226   0.0284 *
#> x             3.1176     1.3091   2.381   0.0192 *
#> groupB        0.1509     0.9455   0.160   0.8735  
#> groupC       -0.5732     0.8772  -0.653   0.5150  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.72 on 96 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.06147,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.03215 
#> F-statistic: 2.096 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: 0.1058

anova(model2, model1, test='F')
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: y ~ 1 + x + group
#> Model 2: y ~ 1 + x
#>   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
#> 1     96 1328.4                           
#> 2     98 1338.3 -2   -9.9017 0.3578 0.7001
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>